# Как сгенерировать случайное 64-разрядное целое число

Tags: c#, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Как сгенерировать случайное 64-разрядное число (типа `long`, он же `Int64`) на C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[из social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb9c7f4d-5f1e-4900-87d8-013205f27587/64-bit-strong-random-function?forum=csharpgeneral)

Можно так:

```
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random(); // create it just once and reuse
    private ulong Get64BitRandom(ulong minValue, ulong maxValue)
    {
        // Get a random array of 8 bytes. 
        // As an option, you could also use the cryptography namespace stuff to generate a random byte[8]
        byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(ulong)];
        rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
        return BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0) % (maxValue - minValue + 1) + minValue;
    }
```

или так:

```
    public static ulong Get64BitRandom(ulong minValue, ulong maxValue)
    {
        // Get a random array of 8 bytes
        byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(ulong)];
        rnd.NextBytes(buffer);

        if (minValue == ulong.MinValue && maxValue == ulong.MaxValue)
            return BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0);

        ulong modValue = maxValue - minValue + 1;
        return (BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0) % modValue) + minValue;
    }
```

Comment: как получить битовая пестовление на `1` и `0`

Comment: Почему не взять просто (rnd.Next() << 32 | rnd.Next()) ?